# Bind Command to a Button inside ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

My View

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding pagination.PageList}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">
            <Button Content="{Binding}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                    **Command="{Binding Path=testCommand}"**
                    Width="20" Margin="10,0"></Button>
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

I want to bind `testCommand` for the button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is `testCommand`? Is it in the data item in the view model that also contains `pagaination.PageList`?

Comment: my ViewModel has Pagination and testCommand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `RelativeSource` binding to access the `DataContext` (your view model) of the `ItemsControl`.

```
<Button Content="{Binding}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Command="{Binding DataContext.testCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
        Width="20"
        Margin="10,0"/>
```

Comment: It's Working like a Charm!